# Importing sharepoint list into external application

Tags: c#, vb.net, sharepoint-2010

i will use c# and vb.net for my project.

i need to build an application that must cross information from multiple data sources. i was wondering if there is a way to import specific list from share point site as XML format without using the microsoft.sharepoint.client.dll and  microsoft.sharepoint.client.runtime.dll?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint shares its data through a web service. Navigate to http://(site_url)/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/(list_name) and you will see it. So just find a library on your programming language that reads it.

Comment: hi Filipe, i tried to access the xml via the browser but that is the error that im getting from the server: "The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details."

Comment: The list might be corrupted. Btw, the protocol used by the sharepoint webservice is called OData.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using Ajax calls(Pure Javascript) if you are having sharepoint 2013 environment

```
var varAjaxcall = $.ajax({
url: "https://SiteURL" + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items?$select=Title&$top=10000",
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
headers: {
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
}
});
```